# git diff between current date and some times ago in GitPython

Tags: python, git, git-diff, gitpython

I am using GitPython to find the changed file for a certain period of time (for example now and 1 week ago):

```
 repo = Repo(self.repo_directory)
 for item in repo.head.commit.diff('develop@{1 weeks ago}'):
     print ("smth")
```

but nothing happens even by changing the number of weeks to different number, which means there is no diff detected for that time period. If I change `'develop@{1 weeks ago}'` to `'HEAD@{1 weeks ago}'` then the number of changes is huge which is not correct for a week. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remember that `ref@{reflog-selector}` is just a way of specifying one particular commit hash. The reflog selector chooses how Git looks at the reflog for the given ref—the one preceding the `@`—and picks out one of its values. Use `git reflog <ref>` to show the reflog for that ref: the hash ID your reflog expression picks will be one of those hash IDs.

Comment: Really, look at *your* reflogs. Your reflogs are *yours* —they reflect the activity *you* did in *your* repository. They do not reflect activity in any other repository! If someone changed some file in *their* master ten years ago, and you connected your Git to their Git yesterday and got their new commits yesterday, *your* reflogs will say "this happened yesterday".

Comment: Thanks Torek, So what do you suggest to find the list of changed file (add, delete,...) in a repo? using GitPython or some other Python packages if you're aware of?

Comment: I wouldn't try to do it in Python at all. First, I'd define what we mean by "changed file", because Git doesn't store changes. Git stores commits. Commits are snapshots. You can't have a change if you only have *one* snapshot; to get changes, you must pick *two* snapshots, and compare them. Which two snapshots do you want to compare? Once you've figured that out, the next step is to locate those snapshots. The only solid information you have is their hash IDs and the commit DAG, which doesn't tell you much, but perhaps you wish to trust each commit header, which [continued]

Comment: ... which holds *two* date-and-time stamps: "author date" and "committer date". Perhaps those hold what you want, in terms of "when some commit happened". You can use `git log --since` and/or `git log --until` to select commits by committer date.

Comment: Interesting, so using probably `committer date` I can find the `HEAD` for that date that and then compare it with the current HEAD and using their "diff" I will be able to get the diff between those two commits => for example using committer date I find the HEAD was number 100 and now the HEAD is 110 then using `....diff('develop@{HEAD~10}') ` I will be able to get all the diffs?

Comment: Perhaps close enough, yes. But you may want to work with raw hash IDs: they identify an exact commit, and don't rely on relative traversal of the graph. (Use `git log --pretty=format:%H` or `git rev-list` to get the correct hash IDs.) Not that relative is *wrong* either, just that if you make a new commit, suddenly what was `~10` is now `~11`. Or, if your commit DAG is quite branchy, you might need `HEAD~3^2~2^2~4^2` or something crazy like that just to get there using relative motions. If you're writing code, this is absurd: the compiler can remember hash IDs!

Comment: The syntax for "ten first-commit steps back from where my own branch name `develop` points now" is `develop~10`, not `develop@{HEAD~10}`. See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions). Remember that for anything involving *any* historical commit, *any* name is just a method by which we have Git find a commit's hash ID.

Comment: I think counting the number of HEAD (develop) position changes will be correct. Since I tried different `develop~count` and then the number of diffs (changes) were reasonable and I was able to see the slight differences between `develop~3` and `develop~4` both as compared (diff) to the current HEAD. Now if I find the HEAD number for the date that I want for example 1 one week ago then I can find the diff using that number => `develop~count` ... I know it looks crazy a bit :D but it will be very helpful to monitor git through Python which then can do lots of fun stuffs w/ that. thanks Torek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussions in the comments I came up w/ the following solution using GitPython (only required code is put here and ignored the rest to avoid confusion)

```
   import git
   from git import Repo
   from git import RemoteProgress

   class MyProgressPrinter(RemoteProgress):
       def update(op_code, cur_count, max_count=None, message=''):
          print(op_code, cur_count, max_count, cur_count / (max_count or 100.0), message or "NO MESSAGE")


   def _get_commits_info(self):
        for fetch_info in self.repo.remotes.origin.fetch(progress=MyProgressPrinter()):
        self.commits_info.append(
            (fetch_info.commit.committed_date, fetch_info.commit))  
        self.commits_info = sorted(self.commits_info, key=lambda x: x[0]) #sort based on committed date


   def _get_the_changed_components(self):
       self._get_commits_info()
       last_date = self.commits_info[-1][0]
       last_commit = self.commits_info[-1][1]
       since_date = last_date - self.time_period * 86400 # for example time_period is 7 (days)
       since_commit = self._get_since_commit(since_date) # finds the since_commit from the sorted list of commits_info 

       for item in last_commit.diff(since_commit):
           if item.a_path.find('certain_path') != -1:
               self.paths.add(item.a_path) #self.path is a set()
```

However, the length of `self.path` is not reasonable to me since it captures too many changes and I am not sure why.  So basically, what I did is: found all the commits, sort them based on `committed_date` and then found a commit (`since_commit` in the code) where its `committed_date` is for `7 days ago`. After that got the diff between the `last commit` in the sorted `commits_info` list and the `since_commit` then saved the `a_path`es into a set.

I also tried another way and got the diff between every two consecutive commits since `since_commit` from the sorted `commits_info` all the way up to the last commit. This way the number of changes is even higher.

Any comments or help? Or do you think it is the correct way of getting diff for a time period? and the reason that the number of changes is higher is just by accident?

**UPDATE and FINAL SOLUTION**

So it seems comparing (diff) two commits doesn't give the changes that have happened between now and sometimes ago because commits before merging may include the changes before the interested time period. For that, I found two solutions, first count the number of `HEAD` changes since that time till the current date, which is not very accurate. For that we can use:

```
 g = Git(self.repo_directory)
 loginfo = g.log('--since={}'.format(since), '--pretty=tformat:')
```

Then count the number of `Merge pull request` string which basically counts the number of times that merging has happened to the repo, which usually changes the `HEAD`. However, it's *not accurate* but let's assume this count will be 31. Then:

```
  for item in self.repo.head.commit.diff('develop~31'):
     if item.a_path.find('certain_path') != -1:
         self.paths.add(item.a_path) #self.path is a set()
```

**The solution that works and is straight forward**

```
  def _get_the_changed_components(self):
      g = Git(self.repo_directory)
      today = date.today()
      since = today - DT.timedelta(self.time_period) #some times ago
      loginfo = g.log('--since={}'.format(since), '--pretty=tformat:', '--name-only')
      files = loginfo.split('\n')
      for file in files:
          self.paths.add(file)
```

Comment: Thanks and Git log is supported in GitPython which made it very easy.

Answer (score 1):

`develop@{1 weeks ago}` would use the [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

> Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of branches and other references were updated in the local repository.

That means your local Git repository might not have recorded locally any operation on `develop` a week ago, while it has recorded anything happening to "HEAD".

If develop was changed remotely and then its history imported locally, `develop@{1 weeks ago}` might not yield anything (because your local reflog would not reference it).

Only [`git log --since/--until`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---sinceltdategt) would operate on *any* date (not just the ones recorded in reflog, which are limited to local operation, and to, by default, 90 days)

But I don't know if GitPython implements that.
Its [`git.refs.log`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.refs.log) module is more based on reflogs entry, which is not helpful in your case.

Comment: if i change the @{1 week ago} to @{10 weeks ago} still give the same result (nothing). So what do you suggest to get all the changes (changed files, deleted, ...) in develop for for example 1 week ago? using GitPython? using HEAD@{1 week ago} also doesn't seem to be correct because the number of changes is huge for the last week in my example which is not reasonable.

Comment: @Alan What I suggested is that the "week ago" notation only works for work you have done locally, not for history imported from a remote repository.

Comment: I see, so how can I track remote repository?

Comment: @Alan POssibly by providing an exact date instead of relying on the "week ago" notation, which in itself, won't always be available.

Comment: I used `repo.head.commit.diff('develop@{1 Dec 2019}}'):` and changed the date from 16th Dec all the way down to 1st Dec but still no output.

Comment: Is there a way to count how many times HEAD has been changed from for example last week? Then use that count to diff as => `repo.head.commit.diff('HEAD~COUNT')` I mean find the . HEAD for the last week and count the number of times that it's changed to this current date?